# if condition inside a function not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter framework and it will display dates in columns where on the row of it will show different dates based on the records on the other columns.

What i am trying to happen is to show the word "active, almost expired, expired" beside the date. Especially on almost expired if the date is less than 7 days from expiry.

eg, Picture of Table:

[image]

**Models : common_model.php**

```
function get_insurance_expiration_date($id){


        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT expiry_date FROM ".tbl_insurance." WHERE expiry_date <= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK");
        if($query == TRUE){

            return $query->row()->expiry_date.','.'Almost Expired' ;

        }else if ($query == FALSE){

            return $query->row()->expiry_date.','.'Active' ;

        }else{

            return $query->row()->expiry_date.','.'Expired' ;
        }

    }
```

**Views : insurance_view.php**

```
<?php
     foreach($cols as $c){
          switch($c){

            //some code here

            case 'expiry_date':                                                                                                 
                echo '<td>'.$this->common_model->get_insurance_expiration_date($record->expiry_date).'</td>';   
            break;


            //some code here

           }
       }
?>
```

When i try to run the code it will display all rows with the same information from the first row,
eg :

**Expired Date**

2016-04-20,Almost Expired

2016-04-20,Almost Expired

2016-04-20,Almost Expired

2016-04-20,Almost Expired

Please help me what i'm doing wrong with the conditions. I'm having a hard time on this one.

Comment: Can you explain it in more specific way ?

Comment: `elsif($query == FALSE)` you're trying to access `$query->row()->expiry_date`.... but `$query->row()->expiry_date` can't exists if `$query == FALSE`

Comment: As far as I can see, you are checking if your query is TRUE, i.e if the query was executed without issue. And you're query is, hence you're getting the "Almost expired", what you properly wanted was to check the data the query returns.

Comment: You also have an `else`..... what can else possibly be if you've already tested from TRUE and FALSE?

Comment: can you suggest what technique i can use inside my if statement?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Codeigniter you need to count num of rows returned:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM my_table');
echo $query->num_rows();
```

So, if `$query->num_rows()==0` you can check it and do your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the date back from mysql. Then evaluate it in php using the datediff function to decide which string to concatenate onto the end of it.